# what is meant by mps(media processing server) developer application. how to create these application

Tags: ivr, avaya

I am learning avaya OD in that, i have read like we can use mps application.So please tell what is meant by mps,how to create those applications.What is the purpose of the mps application. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPS was / is a proprietary IVR system sold by Nortel, now supported by Avaya.

The MPS supports applications written in a proprietary language known as "MPS Developer", "PeriProducer" or "Peripro" - the "Peri" name comes from the original manufacturer Periphonics.

As far as I know, Avaya do not suggest using this tool to produce new IVR applications although lots of legacy systems are still around. The MPS supports VXML based applications so this would be the recommended route of development.

The Avaya Orchestration Designer environment supports linking to legacy MPS applications but it is not something you would want to use unless you had existing applications which needed to be integrated.